# How to get Facebook User Email in Facebook SDK 4.0.1 (Android)

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

In SDK 3 I used `user.asMap().get("email"))` through which i got the email. Now, having upgraded to 4.0, i ain't able to get it from the profile object. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wow ! Seriously? -2? for what?

Answer (score 3):

Now first i would like to say that instead of utilizing your rights to vote someone down, people should rather try to help !

I'm finally posting the answer as it would help someone who is facing a similar issue :)

You just need to add the this part in the onsuccess method.

```
  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                            try {
                                email = graphResponse.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                                updateUI();
                            } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    request.executeAsync();
```

The `jsonObject` has all the data you need :)

```
Here is the complete code





  LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                        new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                                handlePendingAction();


                                 GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                                try {
                                    email = graphResponse.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                                    updateUI();
                                } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        request.executeAsync(); 


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel() {
                                if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE) {
                                    showAlert();
                                    pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                                if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                                        && exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
                                    showAlert();
                                    pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
                                }
                                updateUI();
                            }

                            private void showAlert() {
                                new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginScreenActivity.this)
                                        .setTitle(R.string.cancelled)
                                        .setMessage(R.string.permission_not_granted)
                                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                                        .show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: i would thank you for saying that :
instead of utilizing your rights to vote someone down , people should rather try to help !

Comment: if you have a complete solution On githup  ,,, please give me the link

Comment: Complete solution as in? do you mean complete login to faebook solution for sdk 4+?

Comment: @MaherIsmaail..First download the latest facebook android sdk. Import the projects inside it in android studio/intellij (recommended) or eclipse. There's a HelloFacebook example that contains the login functionality.Also, run this example and get the login thing up and running. Get this much done. Meanwhile i will upload the class that needs changes on github

Comment: https://github.com/abhilash29/FacebookLogin.git

Just compare this class to the one in your project. There are just couple of changes. I've removed lots of code in the class that i've uploaded (which you won't need).